# Check the duplicate entering

Tags: c#

I using this code to entering .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Coonstring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=****;Charset=utf8";
    string cmd = "Insert into project.name_registry (name ) values('" + this.txt.Text + "');";
    MySqlConnection connectionDatabase = new MySqlConnection(Coonstring);
    MySqlCommand cmddata = new MySqlCommand(cmd, connectionDatabase);
    MySqlDataReader myreader;

    try
    {
        connectionDatabase.Open();
        myreader = cmddata.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
        while (myreader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I need when press on this button check if the insert name found messagebox appear tell my the name exists and prevent the add. If not tell me the insert Done. How i can do this.

Regards

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Second of all, have you heard of the EntityFramework, it will solve all your questions :)

Comment: `select count(*) from name_registry where [name] = 'TheName'` And as noted above, watch for SQL injections.

Comment: Third, you are connecting to your mysql database with the root account

Comment: sure after i complete it i will change the mysql account. But till now i didn't got the solution. what i should do about the duplicate entering. I mean i want to prevent the duplicate entering

Comment: As @FrancisDucharme mentioned above, you can just search for the name to see if it currently exists in the database. That query will return >0 if it exists. Also the name column should be set as unique.

Comment: @Francis Where i can this select count(*) from name_registry where [name] = 'TheName'  in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to have this sort of check is in the database itself. Almost all databases can set a UNIQUE constraint on a field. If you set the `name` column in the `name_registry` to be unique, the DBMS won't let you add a second entry with the same name, and an exception will be thrown. This will usually be the best way.

If the DB isn't in your hands and you can't set the column to be unique, you can use the suggestion that @FrancisDucharme and others and query the DB for the given name, and only call the `INSERT` if it returns 0 results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM name_registry WHERE [name] = 'TheName'
```

Note, though that there's no need to call `ExecuteReader`, not for this single-result SELECT statement, nor for the INSERT statement above - you should call `ExecuteScalar`, which will return the single-value result without loading a full-scale `DataReader` that you don't really need.

And lastly, as an addition to the answer, I can't in good conscience let you go on without pointing you in the direction of at least [one tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06) about using parameterized queries in ADO.NET, which not only help prevent SQL injection attacks, but also help clean up the code and make it more readable, in my opinion. There are many out there.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, As previously stated: You have MAJOR SQL Injections visible...

Secondly, You should be using params.

Third, If you

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [ColumnName] = @Param
```